# Count occurrences of an event by date

Tags: matlab, date, vector

I am facing an issue with counting number of occurrences by date, suppose I have an excel file where the data is as follows:

```
1/1/2001 23
1/1/2001 29
1/1/2001 24
3/1/2001 22
3/1/2001 23
```

My desired output is:

```
1/1/2001 3
2/1/2001 0
3/1/2001 2
```

Though `2/1/2001` does't appear in the input, I want that included in the output with 0 counts. This is my current code:

```
[Value, Time] = xlsread('F:\1km\fire\2001- 02\2001_02.xlsx','Sheet1','A2:D159','',@convertSpreadsheetExcelDates); 
tm=datenum(Time); 
val=Value(:,4); 
data=[tm val]; 
% a=(datestr(tm)); 
T1=datetime('9/23/2001'); 
T2=datetime('6/23/2002'); 
T = T1:T2; 
tm_all=datenum(T); 
[~, idx] = ismember(tm_all,data(:,1)); 
% idx=idx'; 
out = tm_all(idx);
```

The `ismember` function does not seem to work, because the length of `tm_all` is 274 and the size of `data` is 158x2

Comment: can you please add the code you already have.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `datetime` instead of `datenum` for converting your date strings into a serial representation, this can make (not only) the whole computation much easier:

```
tm = datetime({
   '1/1/2001';
   '1/1/2001';
   '1/1/2001';
   '3/1/2001';
   '3/1/2001'
},'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Once you have obtained your `datetime` vector, the calculation can be achieved as follows:

```
% Create a sequence of datetimes from the first date to the last date...
T = (min(tm):max(tm)).';
% Build an indexing of every occurrence to the regards of the sequence...
[~,idx] = ismember(tm,T);
% Count the occurrences for every occurrence...
C = accumarray(idx,1);
% Put unique dates and occurrences together into a single variable...
res = table(T,C)
```

Here is the output:

```
res =

         T         C
    ___________    _

    01-Jan-2001    3
    02-Jan-2001    0
    03-Jan-2001    2
```

For more information about the functions used within the computation:

- [accumarray function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)
- [ismember function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)

On a side note, I didn't understand whether your dates are in `dd/MM/yyyy` or in `MM/dd/yyyy` format... because with the latter, you cannot have that output using my approach, and you should also implement an algorithm for detecting the current month and then splitting your data over a monthly (and eventually yearly, if your dates span over `2001`) criterion instead:

```
tm = datetime({
   '1/1/2001';
   '1/1/2001';
   '1/1/2001';
   '3/1/2001';
   '3/1/2001'
},'InputFormat','MM/dd/yyyy');

M = month(tm);
M_seq = (min(M):max(M)).';
[~,idx] = ismember(M,M_seq);
C = accumarray(idx,1);
res = table(datetime(2001,M_seq,1),C)

res =

       Var1        C
    ___________    _

    01-Jan-2001    3
    01-Feb-2001    0
    01-Mar-2001    2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll first give the code and then explain step by step.

code:

```
[Value, Time] = xlsread('stack','A1:D159','',@convertSpreadsheetExcelDates);
tm=datenum(Time); 
val=Value(:,4); 
data=[tm val]; 
a=(datestr(tm)); 
T1=datetime('1/1/2001'); 
T2=datetime('6/23/2002'); 
T = T1:T2; 
tm_all=datenum(T);
[~, idx] = ismember(tm_all,data(:,1));                                      % get indices              
[occurence,dates]= hist(data(:,1),unique(data(:,1)));                       % count occurences of dates from file
t = [0;data(:,1)];                                                          % add 0 to dates (for later because MATLAB starts at 1
[~,idx] = ismember(t(idx+1),dates);                                         % get incides
q = [0 occurence];                                                          % add 0 to occurence (for later because MATLAB starts at 1
occ = q(idx+1);                                                             % make vector with occurences
out = [tm_all' occ'];                                                       % output
```

`idx` of `ismember` is an `1xlength(tm_all)` vector that at position `i` contains the lowest index of where `tm_all(i)` is found in `data(:,1)`. So take for example `A = [1 2 3 4]` and `B = [1 1 2 4]` then for `[~,idx] = ismember(A,B)` the result will be

```
idx = [1     3     0     4]
```

because `A(1) = 1` and the first `1` in `B` is found at posistion `1`. If a number in A doesn't occur in B, then the result will be `0`.

`[occurence,dates]= hist(data(:,1),unique(data(:,1)));` gives the number of occurences for the dates.

`t = [0;data(:,1)];` adds a zero in the beginning so `t`looks like:

```
   0
'date 1'
'date 2'
'date 3'
'date 4'
...
```

Why this is done, will be explained next.

`t(idx+1)` is a vector that is `1xlength(tm_all)`, and is kind of a copy of `tm_all` except that when a date doesn't occur in the file, the date is zero. How does this work? `t(i)` gives you the value of `t` at position `i`. So `t( 1 5 4 2 9)` is a vector with the values of `t` at positions 1, 5, 4, 2 and 9. Remember `idx` is the vector that contains the incides of the of the dates in `data(:,1)`. Because Matlab indexing starts at `1`, `idx+1` is needed. The dates in `data':,1)` then must also be increased. That's done by adding the zero in the beginning.

`[~,idx] = ismember(t(idx+1),dates);` is the same as before, but `idx` now contains the indices of `dates`.

`q = [0 occurence];` again adds a zero `occ = q(idx+1);` is the row of occurences of the dates.